# Javascript isn't firing in <script> but works in the phonegap function onBodyLoad(), why is this?

Tags: javascript, performance, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

Earlier I asked a question about showing or hiding a div when a radio button is selected.  The solution provided is here http://jsfiddle.net/MFJUv/1/

I'm using phonegap.  When I place the javascript code to hide a div within the onBodyLoad() function necessary for phonegap, it works.

However when not using phonegap and placing the same code within a code tag it never fires and the div is never hidden.  Do I need to include another function to fire this once the page has completely loaded?

```
$('#machinedropdown').hide()

$('input').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'radio-choice-h-6c') {
           $('#machinedropdown').show()
        }
        else {
            $('#machinedropdown').hide()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doublecheck your html code: both your div tags do not have closing angle bracket (`<div data-role="content" id="radio"` <-- here). This may prevent script from running if you put it into certain places like right after opening tag.

Comment: Also, to have this code run properly, you need to put it either: 1) into onDeviceReady -- that phonegap specific thing you probably have in your index.html 2) or into $(document).ready(...) -- see answer below 3) or below all of your other tags. Alternatively, you can can pre-set `display: none` with inline style, and for other thing, you can use delegated event binding (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: For jQuery Mobile, never use `.ready`, bind your code to `pageinit` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

similar to phoneGap's `onBodyLoad()` event.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in an appropriate ready handler, but if I had to guess without knowing much about phonegap or the context, all of your code should be handled inside of a

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   // here
});
```